# Bash-Script: stop/abord if is last Sunday in March or October?

Tags: linux, bash, time, date

How can I stop/abort a bash-script when:

- is last Sunday in March?
  OR
- is last Sunday in October?

Both should be checked here and if so the bash script should be stopped/aborted.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: MAYBE THAT WAY

```
weekday=$(date +%a)
day=$(date +%d)
month=$(date +%m)

if [[ ( $month == 03 || $month == 10 ) && $weekday = "Sun" && $day > 24 ]]
then
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "here"? I would use the `date` command to find out which day and month is today. For example, `date +"%a %d %m" | read weekday dayofmonth month` sets the three relevant variables. After that, a little arithmetic and you are done.

Comment: Need to check if today is is last Sunday in March OR
is last Sunday in October and if so exit/stop the bash script, how this can be done?

Comment: You use the `if` statement. It can process boolean expressions with OR. To find out whether it is the last Sunday in a month, first check if it's Sunday, then if it's less then seven days before the end of the month. To end the script, use `exit`. To end a different script, use `kill`.

Comment: By the way, my `date` script in the first comment doesn't work because the variable assignment takes place in a sub-shell, but you can do `weekday=$(date +%a)` and so on. Oh, and `read weekday dayofmonth month <<< $(date +"%a %d %m")` works. And by the way, I still don't understand what you mean by "Both should be checked here". What is "here"? Serverfault?

Comment: Do you have a full version of that if statement for this purpose, I need to check both "dates" in the same statement that is "here" 

Comment: Something like that: `if [[ ( $month == 3 || $month == 10 ) && $weekday = "Sun" && $dayofmonth > 24 ]]`. Not tested.

Comment: Hm do you think that $dayofmonth > 24 is a secure way to check it :/ there must be a better easier way, but thanks for you suggestions anyway.

Comment: Well, if the 24th is a Sunday, so is the 31st. And if the 25th or a later day is a Sunday, there is no other Sunday that month. Luckily, both March and October have 31 days, otherwise the expression would be messier.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have edited my startpost do you think this may correct?

Comment: looks good. Now you have to wait half a year to test it :)

Comment: I get an error by executing it by cron: https://serverfault.com/questions/1058769/8-syntax-error-word-unexpected-expecting how to solve this?

Comment: I need this syntax for sh?

Comment: Your question says bash, though. There is no `[[ ... ]]` in plain Bourne shell. Instead, use `[ ... ]` and adapt the condition to Bourne shell syntax.

Comment: I'm newly in that can you please give me example how i need to change this? very thankfully

Comment: I have not used the Bourne shell for a long time and would have to read the documentation, which I don't want to invest time in. I do remember that you have to replace equal signs with `-eq`, greater signs with `-gt` and the logical operators with `-a` for "and" and `-o` for "or". The `[ ... ]` syntax is actually the same as the `test` command. Check the manual page for `test`.

Comment: Is it maybe like this: `if [ $month -eq 03 ] || [ $month -eq 10 ] && [ $weekday = "So" ] && [ $day -gt 24 ]`

Comment: The `||` and `&&` are unlikely to work. I think you need to replace them with `-o` and `-a`. Again, read the manual page for `test`.

Comment: I tested it and it work in /bin/sh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [8: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")](https://serverfault.com/questions/1058769/8-syntax-error-word-unexpected-expecting)

Answer (score 1):

To have the script work in sh (so it works in cron), do:

```
#!/bin/sh

eval $(date +'m=%m d=%d dow=%w')

if ( [ "$m" -eq 03 ] || [ "$m" -eq 10 ] ) && [ "$dow" -eq 0 ] && [ "$d" -gt 24 ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```